# idos - эмулятор dos

Tags: dos

Доброго времени суток! у меня на ipad установлен idos(dosbox). есть образ 98 винды 98.img весом в 200 мб. он монтируется и запускается:

> imgmount a c:/98.img -t hdd -fs fat
> boot 98.img

но когда я расширяю его до 2 гб, он монтируется, но винда не запускается:

> imgmount a c:/98.img -size 512,63,16,2048 -t hdd -fs fat 
> boot 98.img

в чем может быть проблема?

и еще вопрос - можно ли сделать так, чтобы когда запущена винда были видны другие монтированные диски, с какой-нибудь папкой например?

Comment: когда была 98 винда, 2 гигабайта это была большая роскошь. И если я правильно помню, то она может рулить до 768Мб памяти. Но народные умельцы патчат винду. и она работает.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я знаю 98 поддерживает до 512 Мб памяти. При увеличении объёма RAM выше этого предела возникают ошибки нехватки памяти при запуске некоторых приложений.

Почитать можно тут - http://www.ixbt.com/soft/windows9x-memory.shtml